# BigQuery: can I lower querying costs by storing data in multiple tables?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have single table, currently with over 43 million rows in BigQuery that stores data samples. One of the fields is "owner_id". All my queries are done with respect to a single owner.

Example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `mydataset.mytable` 
WHERE owner_id = "owner23" AND color = "red"
```

Would creating a table for each owner lower my BigQuery query costs? I suspect querying the entire table with `WHERE owner_id = "owner23" AND color = "red"` requires more GBs to be processed than querying a table with only owner23's data and using `WHERE color = "red"` . While I suspect this is true, I wanted to confirm.

Also, would splitting my data across multiple tables cause storage costs to increase?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Would creating a table for each owner lower my BigQuery query costs?

Theoretically - Yes. You are charged for only data in the columns you query – no matter how many rows are qualified per your WHERE clause. For example if you have 10 clients with relatively even data – cost of your queries can be up to 10 times lower – or in case of just COUNT(1) and no other WHERE clauses - it will be $0(Zero!)
There is a small catch, if query cost is non-zero – the minimum charge is as for 10MB – so if your split tables small and size of involved columns less than 10MB – you still will be charged as for 10MB

Practically – potentially "cost" of managing multiple tables can be high, so you need to compare and decide for yourself

> Would splitting my data across multiple tables cause storage costs to increase?

Storage pricing is prorated per MB, per second – so No – storage cost will not increase

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery pushes filters down to the table storage, particularly for simple queries such as this.  You can read about filter push down [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-plan-explanation).  Note that Standard SQL has more powerful optimizers from this perspective.

So, I don't *think* that you would get much benefit.  However, you might want to test and see if it works.  I sincerely doubt that the benefit would be worth the extra complexity of managing the separate tables.

Answer (score 0):

Your storage costs wouldn't be impacted since the overall data stored is the same. There will be additional table metadata but that shouldn't impact your storage costs. Query costs will reduce since the data scanned for queries is reduced by 10X.

Having said that, this isn't the recommended way to achieve your use case on Big query. BQ explicitly recommends to avoid creating shared tables, consider this example for date shards -  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-communication#avoid_tables_sharded_by_date

What you should instead consider is [clustering](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables) your table by `Owner_id`. It has following advantages

- Exact same computational savings([analysis pricing](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#analysis_pricing_models)) as sharding tables by owner_id
- No additional table metadata or access control overhead, you don't need to maintain ACLs for all sharded tables!!
- Reduced Ingestion time complexity, i.e even if a new owner is created, clustering will handle it, whereas you need to handle the new table creation if you chose to create separate tables for each owner

Also clustering is free, with only one drawback which is load time overhead which isn't significant. Refer to this old post, which walks you through clustering basics - https://hoffa.medium.com/bigquery-optimized-cluster-your-tables-65e2f684594b